# The mesh is compressed during the array along circle curve. How I solve this problem?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

Please guide me how to solve the problem and why is it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of how the mesh looked like before being 'compressed'?

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati     I add  it. Thank you for your help

Comment: @moonboots    I share my file. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

- Apply the rotation and scale of both the curve and the object.
- Select *curve.001*, in *Edit* mode select all and right click > *Set Curve Radius* >1 and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Select the object and right click > *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry*, then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, and in the *Curve* modifier choose *Deform Axis > X*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I forget apply Transform  mesh and curve.